# How do I find the mode of a column of categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the most repetitive value (which is the mode) of a column of categorical data and fill the blank cells with this value.

"Embarked" column has only three values: S,Q,C

When I try to calculate mean and median it gives an error already, because its no numerical value, but I can take a mode of this column, when I try this part of code it doesn't give an error:

```
embarked=df_missing['Embarked']
df_missing['Embarked']=df_missing['Embarked'].fillna(embarked.mode())
```

But it also doesn't fill the empty cells. How can I find the mode of this column.

Comment: check the cells for blank strings, like `''` or `' '`,...

Answer (score 3):

That should be working, but try this approach.

First try `df_missing['Embarked'].value_counts()` and see whether you get what you expect.

Then try:

```
embarked_mode = df_missing['Embarked'].mode()
df_missing['Embarked'].fillna(embarked_mode, inplace=True)
```

If your columns doesn't contain cells aren't actually Na then as @Quang Hoang says, it may be that you have empty strings. In this case you can try:

```
embarked_mode = df_missing['Embarked'].mode()
df_missing['Embarked'].replace('\s+', embarked_mode, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i tried both of your solutions,its counts values but it doesnt fill the empty places.Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: What were the results of the value counts?

Comment: I dont remember the numbers of values but it was counted,i did what i want to do with the code below .

Comment: `embarked_mode = df_missing['Embarked'].mode()[0]
df_missing = df_missing.fillna(df_missing.Embarked.mode()[0])`